# Spring Controller: Custom annotation with combined Spring annotations does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have properly working Spring Controller, where I have a method mapped in a following way

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/users"
    consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public UserResponse retrieveUsers() {
    return new UserResponse();
}

@RequestMapping(
    value = "/contracts"
    consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ContractResponse retrieveContracts() {
    return new ContractResponse();
}
```

This works fine, `GET` requests are served as accepted, and in case of for example `POST` I am receiving proper `405` status code.

Now I want to introduce custom combined annotation, not to have the same bunch of annotations in each and every method.

My custom annotation looks like,

```
@RequestMapping(
        consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Get {}
```

Accordingly, I change the method to

```
@Get
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public UserResponse retrieveUsers() {
    return new UserResponse();
}
```

In this case I can see that whatever type of request I send to `/users` it is served properly. For example even if I do `POST`, I see response. So the `@RequestMapping` does not work properly.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to make controllers behave properly with custom combined annotation?

Comment: Why did you think your `@Get` was going to work like that?

Comment: Why not? In fact it is working, however not properly. At least it returns properly status code for example. I assume that When I put ```@RequestMapping(value = "/users")``` it actually overrides the mapping in my custom annotation, as the other annotation in ```@Get``` are working in fact.

Comment: Did you try combining the @RequestMapping to one annotation and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Why not have your `@Get` annotation accept a `value` and use the `value` for your `@RequestMapping` that way you do not have to separate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the `@RequestMapping(value = "/users")` on `UserResponse#retrieveUsers` replaces the `@RequestMapping` on the `@Get` interface.

See if this works:

```
@RequestMapping(
        consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Get {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};
}

@Get(value = "/users")
public UserResponse retrieveUsers() {
    return new UserResponse();
}
```

You may be interested in [GetJson](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-composed/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/composed/web/rest/json/GetJson.java) in the [spring-composed](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-composed) project.

Note that [@AliasFor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) was only released with Spring 4.2. It's not available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite the `@RequestMapping` annotation you had set up in your `@Get` annotation. Therefore it specifies only the `value` part of the request mapping, leaving all other properties to default.